# acmart ACM-Reference-Format, citations sorted by author name instead of order of apparition

Tags: natbib, acmart

I am using the ACM template to write my article (i.e. `\documentclass[sigplan,screen]{acmart}`) and I am having trouble with the bibliography.

If I use the `unsrt` bibliography style:

```latex
%...

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibli}

\end{document}
```

Then my citations appear in order of apparition in the text on the last page and are numbered accordingly.

But when I use the `ACM-Reference-Format`,

```latex
%...

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{bibli}

\end{document}
```

The citations are sorted according to the author's name on my last page. In my text, the first citation starts with number [11] (the first author I cite is the 11th in the alphabetical order).

How can I get the ACM-Reference-Format to sort the citations according to their order of appearance in my text?

I have tried fiddling with `\citestyle{acmnumeric}` `\setcitestyle{numbers,nosort,compress}`, without luck so far.

Comment: Please proofread your question. I'm thinking some of those `\bibliography{...}` commands should be `\bibliographystyle{...}`?

Comment: Maybe the ACM doesn't like bibliographies in order of appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the solution you are looking for, but you can use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` instead of `ACM-Reference-Format`.

```latex
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibli}
```